# how to open pdf when action sheet item is tapped - sencha touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

```
 forMSDSPDF: function (list, index, item, e) {
     var actionSheet = Ext.create('Ext.ActionSheet', {
            items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'OPEN PDF OF THIS ITEM',
                    handler: function () {
                            var viewer = Ext.create('Ext.ux.panel.pdf', {
                                    fullscreen: true,
                                    layout: 'fit',
                                    src: 'http://cdn.mozilla.net/pdfjs/tracemonkey.pdf',

                            });
                            Ext.Viewport.add(viewer);
                    },
                    ui: 'confirm'
            }, {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    ui: 'decline',
                    scope: this,
                    handler: function () {
                            actionSheet.hide();
                    }
            }]
    });
    Ext.Viewport.add(actionSheet);
    actionSheet.show();
 }
 });
```

The code above is a controller function for the view that contains list of items and on list item tap it pop up action sheet with 2 buttons ,one to open pdf and other to decline, my test pdf is working fine but I want to open pdf file on action sheet item tap,,it is not raising any error but it is not opening any view. Any kind of help would be appreciated.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me, are you including in your app.json the required files: compatibility.js and pdf.js ?